ACS37800 Voltage and Current Problem
I bought 3 ACS37800 integrated circuits to use in the system. These integrated circuits will measure Voltage and Current for each phase of a 3-phase system. However, while I can measure Current without any problems, I cannot read the Voltage measurement correctly because it shows a voltage value of 3-5V. Can you help me with this?
Multimeter Voltage = 230VAC
Multimeter Current = 6A
Sensor Measurement(Voltage) = 5V it’s not correct
Sensor Measurement(Current) = 6A it’s correct



If you look at the section "CONFIGURING THE DEVICE FOR AC APPLICATIONS" of the datasheet, you'll see that the reported voltage is the actual voltage difference between the VINP and VINN terminals, not the line voltage.
To convert from the measured voltage to the line voltage, you need to use the ratio, as detailed in the datasheet.
 (Image taken directly from the  ACS37800 datasheet.)

  ACS_L1.setDividerRes(2000000);
  ACS_L1.setSenseRes(2200);

To me, the schematic diagram suggests values of 4000000 and 2700, respectively.
What type are/where is the documentation for ACS_L1 and Serial?
